# how free unsigned pointer array and it's elements (calloc)

Tags: arrays, pointers, free, unsigned, calloc

What is the best way to free unsigned pointer array allocated with cmallc?

```
 uint8_t *buf;
 buf = cs_calloc(ca->len + 13);
```

i do like this , but i know this is not quite right , since i got compile warning :

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘free’ makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast

```
for (i = 0; i < ca->len + 13; i++)
{   
 free(buf[i]);
buf[i] = NULL;
}

free(buf);
```

here is cs_calloc code :

```
void *cs_calloc(size_t size){

 return (calloc (1,size));
 }
```

my question are
1. the way i free , buf , i mean first free each of array's element in a loop (free (buf[i])
is correct? do i need to free the elements of array , and the free the array as above

1. why do i get that compile warning , and if it's wrong , could somebody please correct the way i free the allocated memory (please write me the code how should be corrected ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `free(buf)` and nothing more - so just drop the `for` and you're set. Trying to `free(buf[i])` is wrong and will trick the library into treating `buf[i]` (a small integer) as a pointer.

There's one and only one simple rule: only `free` what you received from `malloc` or `calloc`.

---

> why that compile warning happened

You got the warning because you called `free` with an integer when `free` expects a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for replying , ok , i will do what u recommend me to do , just for my sane of curiousity , i also want to know , why that compile warning happened? i mean , now after reading your post , i got that i don't neetdto free array's element , but i also want to know , if i have to free that , what change i do need to the free , to not get that compile warning

Comment: so if i just want to fix that warnining , the code should be changed like this (now after reading your comment i know it's not needed , just i want to know how fix this warning:   for (int i=0 ; i <len+3 ; i++ )      { free (&buf[i])}  this is right for fixning the warning?

Comment: @nimatajfar That would still crash the program but would indeed prevent the warning.